# Qt: how to remove unused frameworks/libs when building applications?

Tags: macos, qt, dynamic-linking

I'm using QtCreator to build application frontend. However, when running Qt's deployment tool, i.e., `windeployqt` and `macdeployqt`, the resulting app bundle contains lots of frameworks that are not used in the application such as the QtNetwork.

My test app is just a hello-world GUI app, without referencing non-GUI libs. But if I remove some unused Mac Frameworks from the app bundle (tested only on Mac), then the app crashes. This bothers me because it contradicts the promises of dynamic linking.

What is the correct way of stripping off unused libs with QtCreator? Or should I switch to Xcode/VisualStudio?

Answer (score 0):

Tests reveal that in my case `QtNetwork` and `QtVirtualKeyboard` can be safely removed, but not `QtDbus` or `QtPrintSupport`. So to remove dependencies on Qt frameworks, it should be as easy as to delete the truly unused ones.

I was surprised that although DBus seems a Linux tech, it is still used on macOS and Windows.